# BIND - SERVFAIL errors when using views

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

Running bind 9.8.2 and getting servfail errors when querying a host that resides in one of my views. Here is a snip of my conf file.

```
view "insideview" {
    match-clients { 192.168.100.202; };

    zone "internal" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/db.internal.com";
        notify yes;
        allow-update { none; };
    };

    include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
    include "/etc/named.root.key";
};

view "external" {
    match-clients { any; };

    extzone1
    extzone2
    extzone3
    extzone4 
    etc, etc...
};
```

The failures only occur when my client that's in the match list (192.168.100.102) tries to query a host in the internal zone in the internal.com db file. Here is my db file.

```
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     dns.testlab.net. root.testlab.net. (
                      2015012877
                      28800   ; refresh  8 hours
                      7200    ; retry    2 hours
                      864000  ; expire  10 days
                      86400  ; min ttl  1 day
)
                    IN      NS       dns.testlab.net.

server1             IN      A       192.168.155.206
```

So when I query server1.testlab.net from 192.168.100.202 I get the servfail. I turned up debugging and here is output from logging.

```
12-Aug-2016 10:57:59.764 query-errors: debug 1: client  192.168.100.202#41591: view insideview: query failed (SERVFAIL) for  server1.testlab.net/IN/A at query.c:6569
12-Aug-2016 10:57:59.764 query-errors: debug 2: fetch completed at  resolver.c:3076 for server1.testlab.net/A in 0.000047: failure/success  [domain:testlab.net,referral:0,restart:1,qrysent:0,timeout:0,lame:0,nete rr:0,badresp:0,adberr:2,findfail:0,valfail:0]
```

And here is what /var/log/messages looks like after a service reload:

```
 received control channel command 'reload'
 loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
 reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
 using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
 using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
 no IPv6 interfaces found
 sizing zone task pool based on 18 zones
 Warning: view insideview: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
 Warning: view extview: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
 reloading configuration succeeded
 reloading zones succeeded
 zone internal/IN/insideview: loaded serial 2015012877
 zone testlab.net/IN/extview: zone serial (2015091713) unchanged. zone may fail to transfer to slaves.
 zone testlab.net/IN/extview: loaded serial 2015091713
 received control channel command 'stats'
 dumpstats complete
```

If I query the DNS server from another host IP that falls in the "any" list I can get a result returned, but only for zones listed in the "external" view, so that works as expected. Can anyone help me figure out why my internal view is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
view "insideview" {
match-clients { 192.168.100.202; };

zone "internal" IN {
```

to this:

```
view "insideview" {
  match-clients { 192.168.100.102; };

  zone"testlab.net" IN {
```

Now works as expected.